# How do you position an image over top of two divs/containers?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sticky

I have a web mockup I've been asked to make where a transparent PNG sits on top of two divs multiple times (in multiple rotations). I've built the site using Bootstrap 4.1, so I'm using containers/rows/col to format the site.

```
<section class="one">
    <!-- .container, .row, .col for content -->
</section>
  <img src="flowers.png">
<section class="two">
    <!-- .container, .row, .col for content -->
</section>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odPZqN

So what is the recommendation for having an image sit atop of two containers? The best solution I can find right now is to use a JS library called [Tether](http://tether.io/) but that's by far from a lightweight solution. If the site is adaptive/responsive, absolution position is out of the question.

Code pen using relative/absolute: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxvmMX

I've tried looking at floating left and while that gave me a good start, it seems to interact with the content unfavourably, pushing the text around when I rather not have it move at all.

Codepen using float: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrVpor

What do you think my options are here?

Mockup:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, using media queries to position the image at different breakpoints:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
}

#flower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

// This is just an example - experiment with values that work for you.
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    #flower {
        left: 10px;
        top: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <section class="one">
      <!-- .container, .row, .col for content -->
  </section>
    <img src="flowers.png" id="flower">
  <section class="two">
      <!-- .container, .row, .col for content -->
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I like it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxvmMX, but it isn't an adaptive/responsive solution, no?